# is it possible for attackers to manipulate dart flutter app while runtime?

Tags: flutter, dart, compilation

i'm 3-season old flutter dev and recently got afraid of hackers since there
are so many awesome sources in the web reverse-engineering dart language. i guess this question could seem like a stupid question for the gurus in this field, but i want to make the issue clear for myself. So, the question is..

is it possible for potential attackers to manipulate any code with their bad intentions? For example, is there any possible way to detour the pre-compiled dart app so that they might ignore important condition-checking codes?

The word 'compile' makes me somehow feel safe but the features like hot reload or restart make me worry about the guru hackers contravening the whole mechanisms in their way..! Hope there would be cool answer! Thank you in advance [:

Comment: You should never trust the client in your application since a bad actor can always figure out what your application does and e.g. skip checks or just make the API calls without using your app. Always have checks on the server-side to make sure nothing bad can happen for the overall application (e.g. a bad actor cannot do more than destroy its own user). In the end, your application will always be machine instructions which can be decompiled and analyzed even if you are using obfuscation. But obfuscation does make it a lot more troublesome to make e.g. a fake app without your checks.